# "He gets away with anything."

Tags: word-choice, polarity-items

Can someone tell me why "anything" is used in sentences like this

> He gets away with anything.

I thought it had to be "everything" meaning the person can do whatever they want without worrying about consequences.

> He gets away with everything.

Comment: It sounds a little odd to me too. Although it's not ungrammatical, I think I would expect to hear "He gets away with everything" or "He can get away with anything" instead.

Comment: Where have you seen it used in sentences like this? Some references would help. See the [Details, Please](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) meta post for more tips.

Comment: A lot more hits when googling and also a lot more common in ngrams https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=get+away+with+anything%2Cget+away+with+everything&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cget%20away%20with%20anything%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cget%20away%20with%20everything%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Your sentence in this question doesn't match the hits on the ngram. The hits on the ngram say things like, "I didn't think I could get away with anything" or "We could get away with anything as long as we were careful." [Look more closely](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22get%20away%20with%20anything%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en&safe=active&gws_rd=ssl).

Answer (score 3):

> He gets away with anything

I think that most people would feel that this sentence is not right.

It's dangerous to use NGrams like [the one that you quoted](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=get%20away%20with%20anything%2Cget%20away%20with%20everything&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cget%20away%20with%20anything%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cget%20away%20with%20everything%3B%2Cc0) unless you check at least some of the actual references that NGram finds. In this case, looking at the first five instances of "get away with anything", we have

> Art can get away with anything
>   We could get away with anything

This is OK because it's not saying that art **does** get away with everything, it's saying that art **can/could** get away with anything.

> Don't try to get away with anything
>   I didn't think I would get away with anything
>   they never let me get away with anything

This is OK because when you use a negative, **everything** gets inverted to **anything**.